# Writing into a file only if the file content is different from the new data

Tags: node.js, linux, file, filesystems

I want a code like this:

```
fs.writeFile(fullFileAddress , data, function (err)
{
    if(err)
    {
        if(err.code == 'ENOENT')
        {
            console.error( new Error(`#Space. Can not save file. message: ${err}`.red) );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("#eJS. %s created.", fullFileAddress);
    }
});
```

Do I have to read the file frist and then compare it with the data variable? and if would not be same, then I write into the file?
Or maybe there is a better way for this?

Comment: Does it matter if you overwrite the file with identical data?

Comment: Yes, when you write into a file, you change some attributes on iNode

Answer (score 0):

An elegant alternate would be to compare the [`stats.mtime`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_stats_mtime) which comprise the last modified time of the file against the time of data dispatch rather than the file content against the data.